# How can I apply for $10/month internet, if I rent privately but am indigent?

Tags: canada, services

From [CBC's article](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/ottawa/cheap-internet-low-income-family-1.4695281), this low price appears restricted to low-income housing organization tenants. But I don't live in one. I rent privately in Ontario. Thus how do I apply?

Or must I email ISPs separately and beg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you have posted is about the [Connecting Families Initiative](https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/111.nsf/eng/home). A family becomes eligible for the discounted internet service by receiving the maximum Canada Child Benefit. It doesn’t appear to have anything to do with where you live. (The mention in the article about “community housing” was referring to a previous, similar program.)

According to the [program’s FAQ](https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/111.nsf/eng/h_00002.html), families will be randomly selected to participate from all of the potentially eligible families and sent an invitation letter from the government containing  an access code. There is nothing you can do to sign up until you receive this letter.